# Java SWT: how to delete the selected row in a SWT table

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I have implemented one SWT table having a button widget in one column. On click of a button I am deleting the entire row. But I don't understand how to refresh/redraw/update the table.

```
Table processListTable;
TableItem tableItem;
Image deleteImage = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/trash.gif").createImage();

private void addRowInTable() {
    tableItem = new TableItem(processListTable, SWT.FILL);
    tableItem.setText(0, "value 1");
    tableItem.setText(1, "value 2");

    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(processListTable);

    final Button deleteButton = new Button(processListTable, SWT.PUSH | SWT.FILL);
    deleteButton.pack();

    editor.minimumWidth = deleteButtonButton.getSize().x;
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
    editor.setEditor(deleteButtonButton, tableItem, 2);
    deleteButtonButton.setImage(deleteImage);
    deleteButtonButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new SelectionListener(tableItem, checkButton));
}

class SelectionListener implements Listener {
    TableItem item;
    Button deleteButton;

    public SelectionListener(TableItem item, Button deleteButton) {
        this.item = item;
        this.deleteButton = deleteButton;
    }

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        this.deleteButton.dispose();
        this.item.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check SWT snippet [remove selected items from Table](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet53.java).

Just call `table.remove(int rowIdx);` instead of `item.dispose();`

Comment: remove is not working. as i have implemented button in column.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    this.deleteButton.dispose();
    this.trash.dispose();
    this.item .dispose();

    Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.getColumn(2).pack();
    table.getColumn(2).setWidth(100);
}
```

This is the solution for refresh the SWT table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JFace TableViewer with a model class, delete the object from the model and refresh the TableViewer.